# Page menu with Hide navigation bar on Scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar

I want both menu in Navigation bar extension and hide the navigation bar except the extension when scrolling.

I was able to achieve menu with [PageMenu](https://cocoapods.org/pods/PageMenu) "PageMenu" and hiding the navigation bar through [AMScrollingNavbar](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar)

[image]

But the problem I am facing now is Nav bar hides but the views does not move up with nav bar

```
func loadControllers(){

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let topViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TopNewsController") as!
    TopNewsController

    topViewController.title = "TOP"
    controllerArray.append(topViewController)

    let briefViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("BriefViewController") as!
    BriefViewController

    briefViewController.title = "BRIEFS"
    controllerArray.append(briefViewController)


    let videoViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VediosViewController") as!
    VediosViewController

    videoViewController.title = "VIDEOS"
    controllerArray.append(videoViewController)


    // Customize menu 
    parameters = [
        .ScrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor.navigationBarColor()),
        .ViewBackgroundColor(UIColor(red: 20.0/255.0, green: 20.0/255.0, blue: 20.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .SelectionIndicatorColor(UIColor.whiteColor()),
        .BottomMenuHairlineColor(UIColor(red: 70.0/255.0, green: 70.0/255.0, blue: 80.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .MenuItemFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 14.0)!),
        .MenuHeight(expressTribuneUtilities.convertIphone6ToIphone5(48)),
        .MenuItemWidth(90.0),
        .CenterMenuItems(true)
    ]


    AppDelegate.getInstatnce().nav = self.navigationController as! ScrollingNavigationController
    AppDelegate.getInstatnce().nav.scrollingNavbarDelegate = self


    // Initialize scroll menu
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 64.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

}
```

[image]

Call the Scroll method from the class thats added in the menu

```
        AppDelegate.getInstatnce().nav.followScrollView(tableMainView, delay: 0.5)
```

Comment: what is `self.view` in the last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    AppDelegate.getInstatnce().nav = self.navigationController as! ScrollingNavigationController
AppDelegate.getInstatnce().nav.scrollingNavbarDelegate = self
```

change both line to like this it wont work because you are setting delegate for other instance instead of your navigation .

```
        let navController = AppDelegate.getInstatnce().window?.rootViewController as! ScrollingNavigationController
    navController.scrollingNavbarDelegate = self
```

implement delgate in your controller and set origin of your view w.r.t your 
scrollview.